# Remove suffix from data in col 4 of csv file only (bash)

Tags: csv, text-formatting

I have a csv file that col 4 of contains a suffux of "_1" that I need to remove without disturbing the other columns in the csv that may or may not contain a suffix of "_1".

CSV FILE OUTPUT:

```
    DOM,        PRO,        CONFIG,     CONFIG_CALL,    PATH
    xyz.com,    Num1,       Num1-V,     Asp_tent_1,     /bin/home
    abc.com,    Vel1,       Vell-V,     Asp_App,        /ai/rev/sand   
    123.com,    Xall,       X-V,        X_all_time_1,   /ai/test
    321.com,    Zall,       Z-V,        Z_all_1,        /bin/usr/home
    ...
```

WANTED OUTPUT:

```
    DOM,        PRO,        CONFIG,     CONFIG_CALL,    PATH
    xyz.com,    Num1,       Num1-V      Asp_tent,       /bin/home
    abc.com,    Vel1,       Vell-V,     Asp_App,        /ai/rev/sand
    123.com,    Xall,       X-V,        X_all_time,     /ai/test
    321.com,    Zall,       Z-V,        Z_all,          /bin/usr/home
```

I have tried some awk, grep, tr attempts but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{sub(/_1$/,"",$4)}1' OFS=, input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SED:

```
sed -i 's/_1,/,  /g' file.csv
```

Comment: `without disturbing the other columns in the csv that may or may not contain a suffix of "_1"` -- this will replace all _1's regardless of their position.

Comment: Yes. But I'm replacing `_1,`  . So it do only for suffix..

Comment: until field 2 or 3 ends in _1

Comment: Hey Jeff/Siva any update to this?  I am finding "_1" removed from more that col 4.  Just not sure how to mod this so it only affects entries in col 4 that end in "_1".  Thanks!